# Whats this ruby function doing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this project I poke at, (I am PHP dev, not RoR), there is this function on a modal.

```
  def task 
    @task ||= if search_key 
      Project.trop_fish.tasks.find(:first, :conditions => ["description like ?", "Search key: #{search_key}%"]) 
    else 
      Project.trop_fish.tasks.find(:first, :conditions => ["(name = ? OR name like ?)","#{task_name}","#{task_name} {%}"]) 
    end 
  end
```

So it's trying to find a task, from the project called trop_fish.
But whats the @task at the top.

Is it, assign the result of the finds from the if block to the @task?

Is it the same as

```
  def task 
    if search_key 
      @task = Project.trop_fish.tasks.find(:first, :conditions => ["description like ?", "Search key: #{search_key}%"]) 
    else 
      @task = Project.trop_fish.tasks.find(:first, :conditions => ["(name = ? OR name like ?)","#{task_name}","#{task_name} {%}"]) 
    end 
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost, not quite.  It is the same thing as this:

```
def task 
  if search_key 
    @task ||= Project.trop_fish.tasks.find(:first, :conditions => ["description like ?", "Search key: #{search_key}%"]) 
  else 
    @task ||= Project.trop_fish.tasks.find(:first, :conditions => ["(name = ? OR name like ?)","#{task_name}","#{task_name} {%}"]) 
  end 
end
```

The `||=` indicates that the variable will only be set to the new value if it is not already set with a different value.  As some people commenting have pointed out/to put it more simply, `@task` will be set to the new value if it is `nil` or `false`.

[This portion of the RoR tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sidebar%3aor_equals) by Michael Hartl is a great explanation of the `||=` operator.

@pguardino brings up a good point in that a PHP programmer may not be familiar with the fact that if there is no explicit `return` statement within a method in ruby, it will return the last non-conditional statement in the method as it's return value, so yes, `@task` is being returned.

There [is another bit of text](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code%3acurrent_user_working) in the RoR tutorial which explains why it is advantageous to use the `||=` operator when returning from a method.  It is useful because it means the first call to the `task` method will perform an operation against the database to retrieve a task, but subsequent calls to the method within the same thread will return `@task` without making calls to the database (since the `@task` variable has already been set.

Comment: +1. just an addition though, the long form would be `@task = @task || (...)`. If `@task` is already truthy then the `or` short circuits and does not get evaluated. Truthiness is important when trying to understand `||=`

Comment: @32bitkid Actually `x ||= y` is equivalent to `x || x = y` - there's a subtle difference which doesn't have any effect most of the time - http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that all these methods return @task. I know that's not obvious to php guys.